# Overlay Capture Details Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am currently working on a site which uses a PDF viewing section. In this section the user can click the PDF to enlarge PDF, print PDF, save PDF or email PDF, all denoted by little icons placed next to the PDF preview image.

What I am looking to do is the following; 
Should a user click on any of those icons, for example rather than bring up an enlarged version assuming the "view PDF" link were clicked, it would bring up a modal contact form for the client to capture or take details from the user. ( such as name // email )

I need a way to ensure that no link ( enlarge PDF, print PDF, save PDF or email PDF ) will work, and instead will bring up this pop-up modal until a user has entered details inside of the pop up modal.

Any feedback/help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as a platform? It makes tasks like this a breeze.

Comment: What it is, the project has already been started by someone else .. inside WP. So I'm looking for a way of doing this without a framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to minimize the amount of custom code you have to write, try using jQuery UI's built-in [Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) feature.

Here's an example of it in use (with a terrible jQuery UI stylesheet, but you're going to change this anyway): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KAjR/1/)

Using that, the jQuery becomes as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I basically need this to be used as a way of bringing up a modal for data collection ( as you have done here ). It's only going to be needed once (for signup etc) and then after that those buttons (#mybutton) will be bringing up other elements ( such as print options etc)

Comment: No problem! If my answer has solved your problem completely, please mark it as correct so others know that you have been helped.